# invalid_grant error using Google service account when time is in sync

Tags: oauth-2.0, ntp

I've been debugging this issue for days, but I can't think of anything else to try to fix this.

**The error**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}'' in /html/cms/php/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:279
Stack trace:
#0 /html/cms/php/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(256): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)
#1 /html/cms/php/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(209): Google_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion()
#2 /html/cms/php/google-api-php-client/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(166): Google_OAuth2->sign(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#3 /html/cms/php/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php(154): Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array)
#4 /html/cms/php/google_calendar_sync.php(41): Google_CalendarListServiceResource->listCalendarList()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /html/cms/php/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 279
```

**My server's clock is in sync**:
 2 Jan 13:35:36 ntpdate[1214]: adjust time server 62.212.76.57 offset 0.003544 sec
(62.212.76.57 being my colo company's time server)

I've triple checked my service account developer credentials at the Google APIs Console (I had a screenshot, but I can't use it because my account is too new :/). I've also successfully subscribed to the calendar service (also can't use the screenshot I made of this).

**My code**:

```
<?php

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php');

    session_start();

    define('CLIENT_ID', 'XXXXXX510496.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME', 'XXXXXX510496@developer.gserviceaccount.com');
    define('CALENDAR_ID', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    define('KEY_FILE', dirname(__FILE__) . '/private/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX881a845ed4e4d2d58eb1-privatekey.p12');

    $client = new Google_Client();

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
     $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
    $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
      'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' . CALENDAR_ID . '/private/full/',
      $key)
    );

    $service = new Google_CalendarService($client);

    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
    echo "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calendarList, true) . "</pre>";

 ?>
```

I've completely run out of ideas, so any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a document that might help you get unstuck:

http://www.tqis.com/eloquency/googlecalendar.htm

Comment: I'm afraid your example doesn't seem to make use of service accounts. I've had success authenticating as a 'web application', but I'm still stuck with this issue. Any further assistance would be hugely appreciated.